# The best way to overwrite an SQLite database table in Android?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

When there is new data available to my Android application I need to completely remove all current entries in one of the SQLite database tables and replace them all with the new data. What is the best way to do this?

Would it be best to run

```
DELETE * FROM my_table
```

or

run a `delete` query for every row in the database

or run

```
database.execSQL(DATABASE_DROP_MY_TABLE);
database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_MY_TABLE);
```

Where `DATABASE_DROP_MY_TABLE` is SQL to drop the table and `DATABASE_CREATE_MY_TABLE` is
SQL to create the table again with no entries.

And then following one of these, insert the new data.

Of course there are probably other ways to do this that I have not thought of.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using SQLiteOpenHelper, you can just close db, delete the whole file and recreate the db:

```
class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  public static final String DB_NAME = "wat";

  public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, CURRENT_VERSION);
  }
}


dbHelper.close(); // dbHelper is your MyDatabase instance
context.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase() // will create empty db
```

Nice thing about this solution is that you won't have to update table resetting code when you add new tables to your schema. It also correctly recreates indexes you might have added.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't complicate things, and simply drop the table with DROP TABLE statement. As the [doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_drop_table.htm)  say:

> The SQLite DROP TABLE statement is used to remove a table definition and all associated data, indexes, triggers, constraints and permission specifications for that table.

You would have clean plate, then create the table again and add your new data.